# do not allow user to select existing user name using php and MySQL and display alert box if user select existing username

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working with php and MySQL my problem is how to make function or code in javascript that alerts users when selecting a user name that already exists and does not allow them to submit registration form.

thanks

Comment: alert('This thread already exists!');

Comment: how to add html in above post using stack exchange

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using jQuery and PDO so it's an ajax username check

Here is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#username').keyup(function() {

        var username = $('#username').val();
        if(username == "" || username.length < 4) {

            $('#username').css('border', '3px #CCC solid');
            $('#tick').hide();
        }
        else{

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "util/UsernameCheck.php",
               data: 'username='+ username,
               cache: false,
               success: function(response) {

                    if(response == 1) {

                        $('#username').css('border', '3px #C33 solid'); 
                        $('#tick').hide();
                        $('#cross').fadeIn();
                    }
                    else {

                        $('#username').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
                        $('#cross').hide();
                        $('#tick').fadeIn();
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   alert('request failed');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The #tick and #cross are just images which are hidden/displayed depending if the username is being used.

The UsernameCheck.php

```
<?php

// your database info here
require '../config.php';

try {
    // create a new instance of a PDO connection
    $db = new PDO(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // if the connection fails, display an error message
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $sql = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue('username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = (int) count($stmt->fetchAll());

    echo $count;
}

?>
```